# JavaScript canvas onhover using canvas lines

Tags: javascript, events, canvas

After hours and days of trying to get this onhover event to work on mousing over a specific line in the grid, I gave up. I searched on StackOverflow, Google, Youtube, literally everywhere on how to get this work but with no luck. I tried with redrawing the grid but no luck. All I want this code to do is, to change the line color to, let's say red. Here's my code snippet below:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");   

function showMenu() {
    var showCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var showMenu = document.getElementById("main");
    var showButton = document.getElementById("button_hidden");

    if(showCanvas.style.display == "none" ) {
        showButton.style.display = "block";
        showCanvas.style.display = "block";
        showMenu.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        showCanvas.style.display = "none";
        showButton.style.display = "none";
        showMenu.style.display = "block";
    }
}
var paths = [];

function drawGrid(w, h) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.canvas.width = w;
    ctx.canvas.height = h;
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (x = 0; x <= w; x += 25) {
        ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(x, h);
        for (y = 0; y <= h; y += 25) {
            ctx.moveTo(0, y);
            ctx.lineTo(w, y);
            paths.push([{x: x, y: y}]);
        } 
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();  
}

drawGrid(650, 650);
```

And this is what I want to do:
https://gyazo.com/a88b7773f7674b0fcbf3f62bee1eff76
As you can see on the picture, I want to highlight let's say those three lines when I hover over them and then change them to normal. I know that it has to do with re-drawing the whole grid again and then add an event listener to get the mouseover event on that specific coordinate, but I simply can't get it to work.

Comment: Before I help, Im confused on whats supposed to happen still. Are you saying when you hover over any lines, you want it to highlight red, and when you move your mouse off it, change it back to black?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do! So when I hover over any line, it changes to red, after I move my mouse from that line it changes back to default (black).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to help you learn about event listeners!

```js
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => { locatePos(e) }); //Run function and pass listener variables

    function showMenu() {
        var showCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var showMenu = document.getElementById("main");
        var showButton = document.getElementById("button_hidden");

        if (showCanvas.style.display == "none") {
            showButton.style.display = "block";
            showCanvas.style.display = "block";
            showMenu.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            showCanvas.style.display = "none";
            showButton.style.display = "none";
            showMenu.style.display = "block";
        }
    }

    function drawGrid(w, h) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.canvas.width = w;
        ctx.canvas.height = h;
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (x = 0; x <= w; x += 25) {
            ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(x, h);
            for (y = 0; y <= h; y += 25) {
                ctx.moveTo(0, y);
                ctx.lineTo(w, y);
            }
        }
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function locatePos(e) {
        drawGrid(650, 650); //Redraw grid to erase previous lines
        let gameX = e.offsetX,    //Account for margin offsets on canvas
            gameY = e.offsetY,
            divisorX = gameX / 25,
            divisorY = gameY / 25,
            gridX = Math.ceil(divisorX),    //Converts 0-649 to matrix number
            gridY = Math.ceil(divisorY);
            //console.log(gameX+" "+gameY);
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        if (checkLarger(divisorX, divisorY) == divisorX) {  //Distinguishes between right side or bottom side border
            ctx.fillRect(gridX * 25, gridY * 25, 1, -25); //Draws the red line
        } else {
            ctx.fillRect(gridX * 25, gridY * 25, -25, 1);
        }
    }

    function checkLarger(a, b) {
        let x = "" + a, //Type convert int to string
            y = "" + b,
            finalx = "",
            finaly = "";
        for (let i = x.search(/\./) + 1; i < x.length; i++) { //Parse everything after decimal
            finalx += x[i]
        }
        if (finalx.length == 1) { //If the deciam is 1 digit (0.60 -> 6) then add a zero (0.60 -> 60)
            finalx += "0";
        }
        for (let i = y.search(/\./) + 1; i < y.length; i++) {
            finaly += y[i]
        }
        if (finaly.length == 1) {
            finaly += "0";
        }
        finalx = parseInt(finalx); //Parse from string to int
        finaly = parseInt(finaly);
        if (finalx >= finaly) { //return the larger value
            return a;
        } else {
            return b;
        }
    }
    drawGrid(650, 650);
```

```html
    <div id="button_hidden">
        <button class="button" id="testBtn" onclick="showMenu()">Back</button>
    </div>
    <canvas width="650" height="650" id="canvas">
    </canvas>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Squarber</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="advLeft">
            <h2>Advertisement Left</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="advRight">
            <h2>Advertisement Right</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="mainMenu">
            <div id="menuButtons">
                <button id="btnPlay" class="button" onclick="showMenu()">
                    <p>Play!</p>
                </button>
                <button id="btnMultiplayer" class="button">
                    <p>Multiplayer</p>
                </button>
                <button id="btnLeaderboards" class="button">
                    <p>Leaderboards</p>
                </button>
                <button id="btnLeaderboards" class="button">
                    <p>Credits</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```